# Why do I sometimes get the information how long a download takes and sometimes not?

Tags: google-chrome

See the following screenshot from Google Chrome:

[image]

I was downloading the following:

- http://mis.haifa.ac.il/~ishimshoni/SegmentCrypt/Download.htm - the database from DropBox ("Images.zip" - no time given)
- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/objectclassrecognition/ - "pixel-wise labelled image database v1" and "Pixel-wise labelled image database v2"

Why do I sometimes get the information how long a download takes and sometimes not?

Comment: I'm not too sure if this is the right place to ask. My thought was that it is probably related to a server configuration, but I don't know which tags would fit.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the server didn't send a [Content-Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header) header. Usually files served directly by the server software will have this header in the associated response as the server handles that automatically but files "streamed" by an application (like files served by using PHP's [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) or files created on the fly) may not have that header due to either the developer being lazy and not adding the extra logic required to determine the file's size or because the file size can't be determined and can be infinite (files created on the fly based on incoming events for example).